# Unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$ for MLR model $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$ where $E(\epsilon ) = 0$ and $Cov(\epsilon) = \sigma^2 V$

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, linear

Consider the MLR model $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$ where $E(\epsilon ) = 0$ and $Cov(\epsilon) = \sigma^2 V$ where  $T$ is not identity matrix. How do I prove or disprove that $ \frac{Y'V^{-1}Y - Y'V^{-1}X(X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}Y}{  n -rank(X)}$ is unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2?$

This is how I attempted this:

$E(Y'V^{-1}Y - Y'V^{-1}X(X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}Y) \\
\\ = E(Y' [V^{-1} - V^{-1}X(X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}]Y )$

I somehow want to use $E(Y'AY) = tr(Acov(Y)) + E(Y)'AE(Y)$

But I am getting stuck in calculating

$tr([V^{-1} - V^{-1}X(X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}]cov(Y)) \\
= \sigma^2 tr([V^{-1} - V^{-1}X(X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}]V) \\
 = \sigma^2tr(I -  V^{-1}X(X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X')$

Help will be appreciated, thanks.